# Is the android Iconography design guide valid for Android 5 / Material design

Tags: android, material-design

The images in the [Iconography design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) have not be updated to Material design. Are the guidelines still valid for Android 5 / Material design?

Comment: you can use below icon from github library, this is valid for material design github.com/johnkil/Android-Icon-Fonts

Answer (score 4):

no they are not the same, you are looking at the holo guidelines these are the material guidelines

http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

As for dimensions (size of launcher and action bar icons, &c), the guidelines are correct.

As for style, there are changes in Material Design, described in the [Style -> Icons section](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons). Indeed, some of the Holo icons (such as edit and delete) are even used as examples of "bad" icons for Material Design.